# How to WRITE to a file from native side (C/C++) on Android 13 Device

Tags: android, java-native-interface, mediastore, scoped-storage

I have a complex image processing application that records images/videos using native code from C++ side, and would like to write to DCIM folder.

I've made this work with Scoped Storage on Android 10 and 11 with the code below:

1.Insert an entry in media store

```
Uri placeholderUri = null;
ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();        
contentValues.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "TEST_VIDEO");
contentValues.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
contentValues.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "DCIM/" + "APP_NAME");
try {
   placeholderUri = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

2.Create ParcelFileDescriptor from the content

```
ParcelFileDescriptor fd = null;
try {
   fd = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(placeholderUri, "rw");
   Log.d(TAG, "new fd: " + fd.getFd());
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

3. Get the full path from open resources the app should have access to by concatenating the fd to "/proc/self/fd/"

```
return "/proc/self/fd/" + fd.getFd();
```

This approach now does not work on Android 13 devices, as I don't seem to have write access to "/proc/self/fd" I could not find any information as to why this wouldn't work on Android 13 but it would for Android 10 or 11.

Is there any way to make this work with MediaStore without using StorageAccessFramework? Idea of relying on users to select the correct folders would be the last option for my clientele, so I would like to rely on MediaStore as much as possible.

Thank you!

Comment: You are not using placeholderUri. What is mediaUri?

Comment: You cannot save *.mp4 files in DCIM directory.

Comment: @blackapps placeholderUri is just mediaUri. I've also saved it to the DCIM just fine using the direct path, I believe since 13 it's one of the places you're allowed to access with read/write permissio, granted that the file is attributed to your app which you can do with the placeHolderUri method I provided above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DCIM seems to be one of few places we have read/write access granted the file is attributed to the app.The initial code I provided in my question is a way to create a file attributed to the app so we can do a write access from the native side.

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) + "/" + albumName + "/" + fileName + ".mp4"
```

Above code works to get the absolute path which the app will have rw access to.

Comment: Are you saying that you do now withhout the filedescripter stuff and /proc/self/fd?

Comment: @blackapps yes, it's not documented, but since android 13 your app will no longer have write access using /proc/self/fd/ method I used to use.

Comment: `the file is attributed to the app` You mean the file is created by the app and hence belongs to the app.

Comment: In Android 13+ devices you do not need the MediaStore to create files in DCIM dirctory. You can do that with classic File means without needing any permission. In DCIM and Pictures directory you can only create image files like .jpg and .png. Not .mp3. Google wants you to place mp3 files in public Music or Video folder.

Comment: I earlier said "You cannot save *.mp4 files in DCIM directory. ". Well you cannot using classical file means but you can using the MediaStore like you did. Great discovery. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: `since android 13 your app will no longer have write access using /proc/self/fd/ method I used to use.` You never had write access to that directory. Being able to use a construct like /proc/self/fd/+filedescriptor does not imply write access to the dir.

Comment: `You never had write access to that directory. Being able to use a construct like /proc/self/fd/+filedescriptor does not imply write access to the dir.`

In case if it wasn't clear, I was never referring to the directory itself but the file created in that directory /proc/self/fd/YOUR_FD.  And, yes I have a write access to this file in Android 11.
This is just a contextual misunderstanding though, if you look at my code I was never attempting to have a write access to the entire directory but the file itself.

Comment: To recap for anyone reading this: 
**For Android 10, 11**: use the method I outlined in my original question,
**For Android 13**: use the accepted answer. 
I don't have Android 12 device to test it against.